# How could Voldemort be killed when Harry's blood runs through them both?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, deathly-hallows

As we know, at the end of *Goblet of Fire*, Voldemort takes Harry's blood into his new body, thus binding Harry to life so long as Voldemort lives due to his mother's sacrifice.

My question is, then, at the end of *Deathly Hallows*, when Voldemort's curse yet again rebounds, how could Voldemort die if he is still anchored to life because Harry still lives? Aren't they still connected through Harry's blood?

Comment: The blood protection ran out after the cemetery incident. Remember "I can touch him now"?

Comment: He isn't anchored to life by Harry's blood. He uses Harry's blood to remove the protection and to return to full life.

Answer (score 4):

I've thought about this before and I suspect the answer is as simple as "**it's one way**".

Dumbledores explanation is as follows.

> “But if Voldemort used the Killing Curse,” Harry started again, “and
> nobody died for me this time – how can I be alive?”
>
> “I think you
> know,” said Dumbledore. “Think back. Remember what he did, in his
> ignorance, in his greed and his cruelty.”
>
> *snip for brevity*
>
> “He took my blood,”
> said Harry.
>
> “Precisely!” said Dumbledore. “He took your blood and
> rebuilt his living body with it! Your blood in his veins, Harry,
> **Lily’s protection** inside both of you! He tethered **you** to life while
> **he** lives!”

It's explicitly stated it's still Lily's protection magic at work here. Voldemort carries it too, but this doesn't mean that he is protected by it (note that Dumbledore does not say "He tethered you both to life"). From this we can assume the magic doesn't protect whoever has the blood, but the person for whom the sacrifice was made. Other carriers just act as neat backups for the original protectee, as it were.